# asp.net-core unresponsive, "Access is Denied." message in logfile

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have published a dnx451 application to IIS 8.0 on Windows Server 2012.

`dnx --version` on the server reports '1.0.0-rc1-16609', the httpPlatformhandler is also installed.

IIS is configured to direct requests on port 80 to the wwwroot folder.

When I attempt to browse localhost:80 on the server, there is no response ('waiting for localhost').

In the logs folder is a file (stdout.log_5428_201648135647.log) with the single entry 'Access is Denied.'

Access denied to what? Clearly at least one of the processes involved has write access to the log folder... I tried applying 'Everybody/Full Control' permissions to the parent folder to help diagnose, but it made no difference.

I can find nothing untoward in the eventlog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application had a database connection string with `TrustedAuthentication`, and SQL Server was causing the 'Access is denied'.

Switching the application pool account to one with database rights fixed it.